# After dynamic filling of <label text="DYANMIC"> DYANMIC</label> cannot retrieve the text again

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I am dynamically filling the label4.text.. I hope to retrieve it for updating in the dbms

```
<asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server"  Font-Bold="True" BackColor="#E3EAEB" 
 Height="25px" Width="300px"><%=Application.Get("topic").ToString()%></asp:Label>
```

In the above code I need to insert `text="<%=Application.Get("topic").ToString()%>` in the `<label>`tag but this cannot be possible due to syntax error or it cannot be done at all.

I have a linkbutton, by clicking on the link button can I retrieve the text of the label.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" Font-Size="Smaller" 
 onclick="LinkButton2_Click">Post to Comment</asp:LinkButton>

protected void LinkButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string dumy=Label4.text.toString();
    // This is return a empty string..
}
```

Please let me know where I am going wrong.. or is there any other way of doing it...
Since I am dynamically filling the `label4.text`.. how to retrieve it?

Answer (score 0):

try this in your server-side code

```
    protected override void OnPreRender(System.EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPreRender(e);
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            Label4.Text = Convert.ToString(Application.Get("topic")); //might be null?
        }
    }
```

Then you should be able to pull the text from that Label in your LinkButton as you have it (capital "Text")

OR!! You could just set the **dumy** string directly to the Application.Get("topic")

If you don't have serverside code I would just do the latter suggestion and make a label on the page like this:

```
<label style="font-weight: bold; background: #e3eaeb; height: 25px; width: 300px;"><%=Application.Get("topic").ToString()%></label>
```

(might want to look into stylesheets and just add a **class="mylabelstyle"** attribute

Answer (score 0):

You can use expression builders for this, we do this all the time.

see [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20210304125044/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/022509-1.aspx)

So after you create and register your expression builder you would do something like

```
<asp:label runat="server" Text='<%$ AppText : "something" %>' />
```